# Finding the Distribution of a Stochastic Integral Expression

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $d_1,d_2 \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $(B_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ be a standard $d_2$-dimensional Brownian Motion. Let $\mu$ be a constant ($d_1 \times d_1$) - matrix and let $ \sigma $ be a  constant ($d_1 \times d_2$) - matrix.

I believe I have shown that the unique strong solution $(X_{t}^{x},B_{t})_{t \in (0,\infty]}$ to the equation

$$ dX_{t}^{x} = \mu X_{t}^{x} dt + \sigma dB_t \ \ \ \ \ \ in \ \  (0, \infty) $$
$$ X_{0}^{x} = x $$

Is given by

$$ X_{t}^{x} = exp(-t \mu) ( \int_{0}^{t} exp(s \mu ) \sigma dB_s + x) $$

The question then asks for the distribution of $X_{t}^{x}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^d $ and $t \in [0, \infty)$. My thoughts are that, since this is a deterministic integrand with respect to Brownian motion, the integral must be a Gaussian vector and so its distribution will be determined entirely by its mean and covariance. But then I have trouble finding the covariance of a vector like this - any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covariance should be given by the multidimensional Ito-isometry

$$  C_t = \mathbb E[(X_t^x-e^{-\mu t}x)(X_t^x-e^{-\mu t}x)^T] = e^{-2\mu t}\mathbb E[\int_0^t e^{s\mu} \sigma dB_s (\int_0^t e^{s\mu}\sigma dB_s)^T] = e^{-2\mu t} \int_0^t e^{2\mu s} \sigma \sigma^T ds = \frac1{2\mu}\bigg(1-e^{-2\mu t} \bigg)\sigma \sigma^T  $$

Comment: Great - thank you very much! Is my argument about the distribution being characterised by mean and covariance correct?

Comment: Yes, $X_t$ is a Gaussian process, meaning that it is fully characterized by its mean and covariance functions. $\mu(t) = e^{-\mu t}x $ as you have probably guessed or known, and the covariance can be computed via the Ito-isometry.

Comment: Great - thanks for your help. I think the main issue was that I'd never heard of the multidimensional Ito Isometry!

Comment: https://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/reiss/sode-lecture.pdf   p14